# Community Promotion Ads - 2012

Tags: discussion, community-ads

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Community Promotion Ads - 2013](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/community-promotion-ads-2013)

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources related to the English language
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently 6) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/2223).

Comment: Sweet! I'm looking forward to learning about events and such.

Comment: [Wut?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wut)

Answer (score 14):

[image: No general reference, please!]

Comment: These ads go on your own site, not on any other site. So, pointing at yourself seems a bit... moot.

Comment: @Grace: Good point, fixed!

Comment: This notice doesn't indicate that it's something you can click on. At first I thought it was a Captain Obvious Public Service Announcement.

Answer (score 12):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]

Comment: Hi all! Academia.SE has a nicely growing community discussing all sorts of matters relating to academic life, from grad student to emeritus professor… We think it could be of interest to part of the EL&U community!

Comment: I like this ad. It certainly caught my attention.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Writing exercise chat]

Comment: I hope it's okay to advertise events on other SE sites here. I figured there's enough cross-pollination between the two sites that there's likely to be interest here. And I designed this ad so it'll look nice on EL&U.

Comment: Isn't it technically typing? XP

Comment: Writers type, conductors wave a piece of wood around in the air while wearing a tux, and it's the job of a painter to cover a canvas because the art public hates the color off-white.

Comment: True.(darn char length)

Answer (score 8):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a sample answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 8):

[image: Write for the EL&U Community Blog!]

Comment: So are you or are you not a lefty???

Comment: @Luke Sinister ego, et tu? :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Is there anything I should improve?

Comment: Your vocabulary?