# Community Promotion Ads - 2013

Tags: discussion, community-ads

As it is December 2012, we are now going to reset our Community Promotion Ads for the new year.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- the site's twitter account
- useful tools or resources related to the English language
- interesting articles or findings for the curious
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **220 x 250 pixels**
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3400).

Answer (score 16):

[image: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/]

Comment: Suggestions are welcome! :)

Comment: Font changed: [PNG](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9TMZ.png), [SVG source](https://gist.github.com/4362126)

Comment: @Mechanicalsnail Like I said in chat, "Linguistics" written in small caps was on purpose. The IPA shadow below is more intended to be a representation of "what's behind the words" rather than an actual projected shadow of a word. I like yours, but it changes what I meant to convey with mine.

Comment: You have a rather glaring space after the *W* and before the *ant*. Did you use some Windows contraption that doesn’t understand kerning or something?  If so, you either have to switch to a font that does not require kerning, or switch to something that knows how to kern.

Comment: Thanks very much; I do appreciate it. Having eaten of the fruit from the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil Kerning, I fear I can never now return to that primeval state of blissful blindness wherein such *lacunae litterarum* would slip past my whilom uncritical notice, howsoever more pacific my life’s road would be but were they to do so. ☺

Comment: @tchrist Once you told me about it I couldn't go back. *The Seen cannot be Unseen*!

Answer (score 11):

[image: English Language Learners Beta]

Comment: Since the site has switched to public beta, I have changed the ad back to the one for the site itself. I guess I was just too anxious to get the site going. The ad now looks like the beta site and has anti-aliased graphics.

Comment: I've voted for this, but it would be good to include some blurb to encourage English language learners to click and ask their (ELL-appropriate) question there. I don't know what, though.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Writing exercise chat]

Comment: Re-posted Neil Fein's ad for Writers.

Comment: Geezers, wow, you beat me to posting the site twitter ad. Were you just waiting for the cycle to hit here?

Comment: *coughs* I was trying to figure out how to pass arguments when I saw the notice.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Italian Proposal]

Answer (score 8):

[image: Write for the EL&U Community Blog!]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Follow us on Twitter!]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted. It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.

Answer (score 5):

[image: No general reference, please!]

Comment: (From the [most popular ad in 2012](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/2292/9001) (+17 -1) to the least popular in 2013! (+10 -7))

Answer (score 4):

[image: Academia Stack Exchange]